# Missing one link in logic of basic unique factorization argument

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, prime-numbers

From page 2 of [The Prime Facts : from Euclid to AKS](http://www.scottaaronson.com/writings/prime.pdf) by Scott Aaronson :

> Thus P/A = R/K. But R is less than P, since it’s a remainder from dividing by P.

**Okay**

> So P/A can’t be in lowest terms;

[ **Why?** ]

> something greater than 1 divides both P
>   and A. But nothing divides P except 1 and itself, so P divides A.

**Okay**

I don't see the link between R being less than P, and P/A having to be *not in lowest terms*, otherwise I follow the argument. Can anyone suggest how I can convince myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P/A = R/K$, and $R < P$, then $R/K$ is in lower terms than $P/A$, so the latter cannot be lowest!

---

So, after discussion in the comments, it transpires that my definition and your definition of "lowest terms" are a bit different. So, here's a bit of work to show they're equivalent:

**Definition:** a fraction $a/b$ is in lowest terms if there do not exist $c$ and $d$ with $c < a$ and $d < b$ such that $a/b = c/d$.

**Remark**: of course if $c < a$ then $d < b$, so the "and" above can be replaced with "or".

**Theorem:** If $a/b$ is in lowest terms, their GCD is 1.

**Proof:** Otherwise you could cancel their GCD and get a smaller fraction.

**Theorem:** ("obvious" but still needs proving) For any given fraction $x/y$, there is a fraction in lowest terms equal to it.

**Proof:** If $x/y$ is in lowest terms, then that's your fraction. Suppose not. By definition, this means there exists $c$ and $d$ with $c < x, d < y$ and $x/y = c/d$. If $c/d$ is in lowest terms, stop. Otherwise, this means there exists an even smaller fraction. Continue in this way – eventually you must stop, because the numerators are getting smaller every time.

**Theorem:** If $x/y$ is not in lowest terms, then $x$ and $y$ have a common factor.

**Proof:** By the previous theorem, there is a fraction in lowest terms to which $x/y$ is equal, say $x/y = a/b$. Then $xb = ya$. So $a$ divides $xb$. But we know that the GCD of $a$ and $b$ is 1, so in fact $a$ divides $x$. Likewise, $b$ divides $y$. So $x = ka$ and $y = lb$, so $ka/lb = a/b$. But then $k/l = 1$, so $k = l$. So $k$ is a common factor of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Oh, since P *must be* a multiple of R **and** A *must be* a multiple of K, because of the equality?

Comment: That's certainly true. How exactly do you define lowest terms?

Comment: I suppose there would be not factor common between numerator and denominator. So if there is then it can't be in lowest terms. Okay, thanks for repairing my logical chain, I think I'm convinced. :)

Comment: Wait, that's not *quite* right. Think of $9/6 = 6/4$. $P$ isn't a multiple of $R$, but that doesn't matter – all that matters is that something *can* be cancelled from $P/A$ because its terms are not minimal.

Comment: Okay, if we say that the GCD of the GCD of both denominators and the GCD of both numerators is not 1, I think that settles it. So something can be cancelled from one side, or both sides. So P *has a* multiple *in common with* R, and A *has a* multiple *in common with K* and these two common multiples *have a* common multiple, that is not 1, then at least one side is not in lowest terms. Is that right? That sounds more right. I thought it still felt funny. Thanks for pursuing and pointing that out.

Comment: Wait, that's not right. Only that when in lowest terms the equality holds. And then each side can be multiplied (denominator **and** numerator) by whatever one likes. And the equality still holds since that is the same as multiplying by 1. Phew. I think *that* settles it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I define it as "a fraction is in lowest terms if there are no fractions with a smaller numerator and denominator to which it is equal". Then it's obvious that $P/A$ is not in lowest terms, and then you need to prove that if a fraction is not in lowest terms, then its numerator and denominator have a common factor. Hold on a sec, I'll edit my answer.